# Residuals Plot : Is it Residuals Vs Fitted or Residuals vs Independent?

Tags: statistics

My basic understanding about Residuals Plot was that it's (standardized) residuals vs Fitted ( Predicated ) value. But doing a google search lead me to a few sites that mentioned that it's the residuals vs independent value. 
[http://stattrek.com/regression/residual-analysis.aspx]

Here is a site that describes my initial understanding..
[http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-you-need-to-check-your-residual-plots-for-regression-analysis]

What's statistically correct method ?

Answer (score 0):

I am certain it's residuals plot is between the residuals and the predicated value. Excel Regression also automatically generates this in the Regression result set.